# Can I use swup with react js?

Tags: reactjs, swup

I'm trying to use swup js with React js. when I import swup and add `const swup = new Swup();`
It shows following error.
How can I fix it.
I added it like this

```
import Swup from 'swup';
const swup = new Swup(); //

export default function TestingComponent(){

return(
    <div>
        <main id="swup" className="transition-fade">
        <div  className="container">
            This component created for test swup js
        </div>
        </main>
    </div>
);
}
```

**Error**
TypeError: Cannot set property 'responseURL' of null

Can somebody help me to fix this out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use framer it will help you. check the blowing link and learn it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHCr554UJ1I

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29899365)